# Elasticseach using NEST to replace an Index with a new one but same alias

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Can anyone tell us what is the best way of creating a new Index to replace an existing one but having the same Alias.

Say we have an existing index named **properties-2019** with alias **properties**.

We would like to replace this with a new index named **properties-2020 but with same alias**.

Do we have to:

1- Create the new index properties-2020

2- delete the old index properties-2019

3- Then add the alias to the newly created index properties-2020

Is there an efficient way of doing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes.

First `_reindex` the data and then rename the alias name.

**Reindex** - mapping, settings, and data

[Reindex Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false  
{
  "source": {
    "index": "properties-2019"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "properties-2020"
  }
}
```

**Rename an alias**

[Update index alias Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions" : [
    { "remove" : { "index" : "properties-2019", "alias" : "properties" } },
    { "add" : { "index" : "properties-2020", "alias" : "properties" } }
  ]
}
```

**Remove old index**

```
DELETE properties-2019
```

---

**Using NEST** - code has not been tested

**Reindex**

```
var reindexResponse = client.ReindexOnServer(r => r 
            .Source(s => s.Index("properties-2019"))
            .Destination(d => d.Index("properties-2020"))
            .WaitForCompletion(false)
            );
```

**Update an alias**

```
var aliasRes = client.Alias(al => al
    .Add(add => add.Alias("properties").Index("properties-2020"))
    .Remove(remove => remove.Alias("properties").Index("properties-2019"))
);
```

**Delete old index**

```
client.Indices.Delete("properties-2019");
```

Comment: I can't find the Alias method anymore (using NEST 7.13.2). Anyone got any clue how this should be done?